# Evaluating $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2-1}{n+3}$

Tags: limits

I've been working for two days with this to no avail. Any clue or tip will be gratefully accepted.

Intuitively, the limit is positive infinity, as this blows up in a similar way to just n.

The way I am supposed to prove it is through applying the definition of a divergent sequence: $\forall M > 0, \exists n_M \in \Bbb N : a_n > M, \forall n \in \Bbb N, n ≥ n_M$

The ideas I've tried are modifying the expression 'downwards'. I need to find some formula in n that is strictly smaller than the rational expression, ideally a polynomial (to avoid the problem of the denominator). Then, I'd just change the n for the real part of M and I'd get my $n_M$.

In similar exercises, it was easy, as the main way was either making the numerator bigger and/or the denominator smaller and you get something useful, but I haven't found that so here. I can think of no way of making a smaller valued expression that gets rid of that pesky $(n+3)$ without making it bigger than the rational expression.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Umm is it sufficient to change numerator as: $\frac{n^2-9+8}{n+3} = n - 3 + \frac{8}{n+3}$ where n diverges

Comment: Simply above part >$ n^2-9$…

Comment: I have been fiddling with it again, and actually have thought that maybe adding -8 to the numerator actually allows me to get rid of the n+3, yep... Lemme see if it all works out.

Comment: Manuel, are you allowed to use "limit laws" such as $\bigl(\lim_{x\to a}f(x)\bigr)\bigl(\lim_{x\to a}g(x)\bigr)=\lim_{x\to a}f(x)g(x)$ to solve your problem, or may you only use the definition of a limit?

Comment: Only def of limit I think. I am thinking I can't really use the n-3, because once I turn it into the real part of n minus 3, I can get a number that isn't Natural, which nM has to be.

Comment: Is my edit correct ? @ManuelDelRíoRodríguez

Comment: @ManuelDelRíoRodríguez: I think you have written down the definition of a limit incorrectly. We say that $a_n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$ if and only if $$(\forall M > 0)(\exists N\in\mathbb N)(\forall n\in\mathbb N)(n\ge N\implies a_n>M) \, .$$By the way, if you want to notify me when you comment, you should write `@Joe` at some point in it.

Comment: Where is the problem here? Obviously, the limit is infinity because the grade of the numerator is bigger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches which rely on some moderately clever algebraic tricks or observations:

#### Add Zero

As pointed out in one comment, a very quick approach is to "add zero" to the denominator in such a way as to permit the cancelation of the $n-3$ in the denominator in a "nice" way.

$$ \frac{n^2-1}{n+3} = \frac{n^2-1+(8-8)}{n+3} = \frac{n^2 - 9 + 8}{n+3} = \frac{(n+3)(n-3) + 8}{n+3} = n - 3 + \frac{8}{n+3}.$$

If $n > 5$, then the last term is smaller than $1$, so you can make the sloppy estimate
$$ \frac{n^2 - 1}{n+3} = n - 3 + \frac{8}{n+3} > n - 3 + 1 = n-2. $$
For any $M> 0$, choose $n_M = M+2$.<sup>[1]</sup>  If $n > n_M$, then $n-2 > M$, and you are done.

#### Bound from Below

Another possibility alluded to in the comments is to bound the expression from below by "something nice".  In this case,

$$ \frac{n^2-1}{n+3} > \frac{n^2 - 9}{n+3} = n-3. $$

For any $M > 0$, choose $n_m = M+3$.

#### Totally Naive Approach

A totally naive approach is to start with some $M>0$.  The goal is to find $n_M$ sufficiently large that $n > n_M$ implies that
$$ \frac{n^2-1}{n+3} > M.$$
Working backwards, we can solve this for $n_m$ (the inequalities play nice, since $M$ and $n$ can be assumed to be positive):
$$n^2-1 > Mn + 3M
\iff  n^2 - Mn - 3M - 1 > 0.  $$
The function $n \mapsto n^2 - Mn - (3M+1)$ is quadratic in $n$, and has solutions
$$ n_{1,2} = \frac{M \pm \sqrt{M^2 + 4(3M+1)}}{2}. $$
Because this function is a parabola which "opens up", any $n$ larger than the larger of the two roots will solve the original inequality.  So choose<sup>[1]</sup>
$$ n_M = \frac{M + \sqrt{M^2 + 4(3M+1)}}{2}. $$

---

[1] It has been pointed out in the comments that $M$ is not a natural number, so these choices of $n_M$ needn't be natural.  This *really* doesn't matter.  The point is to choose $n_M$ large enought that if $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $n > n_M$, then $f(n) > M$.  If the fact that $n_M$ (as I have defined it) is not natural causes problems, replace $n_M$ with $\lceil n_M \rceil$.  Replacing $n_M$ with something larger does not change the essential argument.

Comment: M is not a natural number

Comment: It doesn't really need to be, but if that bothers you, round $n_M$ up.

Comment: It is equivalent, simply allow M to be natural number in the definition. And I think"Totally Naive Approach" is great in this case.

Answer (score -1):

Brute force: n+3 is less than 2n for n>3. And n^2-1 >= n^2/2 for n >= 2. So your fraction is more than n/4 for n > 3.